# libsvm - how to find Euclidean distance in training data?

Tags: matlab, libsvm

**Situation:** I'm trying to use LIBSVM software to classify test data using a classifier trained on a training set. I found out how to do this with MATLAB but one have a problem with training data.

**Question:** how to find "median Euclidean distance between two points" in training data (I used the "a1a" dataset - http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary/a1a ). 
(my idea: i have to find out ALL Euclidean distant between 2 points in data --> sort --> pick the median one )

I wrote C++ code to read the training data from file( a1a ) and calculate the ALL Euclidean distant between 2 points in training data but everything becomes worse because the size of training data is very big for me.

Do we have another method? if you have any advice, please let me know.

Comment: Why do you need to find the " median Euclidean distance between two points "? If you are trying to normalize the data, just use svm-scale. And how does everything become worse?

Comment: in my situation, i have to find out the gramma (in polynomial kernel) equal 0.01γ0 where γ0 equal the median Euclidian distance between two points taken in the training data.